# Two window.open in one function

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a form that opens two new windows with JS function (with pause)

Problem is, that this JS script works correctly in Firefox, but not in other browsers (opens only one window).
Anyone could help?

```js
function win_open1() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (document.getElementById('vl').checked == true) {
      var dok = document.getElementById('vl').value;
    } else {
      var dok = '';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('vb01').checked == true) {
      let href = document.getElementById('va').value + document.getElementById('vb01').value + dok;

      window.open(href, '_blank');
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
    }

    if (document.getElementById('vb02').checked == true) {
      let href = document.getElementById('va').value + document.getElementById('vb02').value + dok;

      window.open(href, '_blank');
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
    }
  });
}
```

part of HTML form

```html
<form id="form">  
<input name="va" id="va" type="hidden" value="https://domain/index.php?op=gt&lang=pol&bdm=">

Type: 
A: <input type="checkbox" id="vb01" name="vb" value="B&w=01ds&rid=B">  
B: <input type="checkbox" id="vb02" name="vb" value="S&w=01ds&rid=S">   
<button type="submit"  onclick="win_open1()">--- search ---</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify. What specifically doesn't work in other browsers? Is there an error message in the console? Which browsers did you try? Please add the HTML.

Comment: no messege - just open one windows, instead of two

Chrome, Edge, Chrome on the mobile....

Comment: Also add sample `html`. for defining the structure and having the used tags.

Comment: `<form id="form"> 
<input name="va" id="va" type="hidden" value="https://domain/index.php?op=gt&lang=pol&bdm=">

Type: </td><td>
A: <input type="checkbox" id="vb01" name="vb" value="B&w=01ds&rid=B"> 
B: <input type="checkbox" id="vb02" name="vb" value="S&w=01ds&rid=S"> 

<button type="submit"  onclick="win_open1()">--- search ---</button>
</form>`  sorry I try ... it is complicated ... this is short of my form of course

Comment: Your form is going to submit and try to run a function at the same time - appears your submit is winning `<button type="submit"  onclick="win_open1()">--- search ---</button>` thus you are not getting what you expect here.  And then you try to add an event handler for an event that has already fired `form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments are saying, there is some issues occuring, I'm not sure how your submitted code works in Firefox, could be some missing code, but I don't see any element named `#vl` for starts.

Secondly for an `async/await` or `Promise` event, I would remove the `onclick="win_open1()" from your` HTML`.

This is important, the `win_open1()` is declaring the `form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {..}` over & over.. so just remove the `addEventListener()` out of the function you are using.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('woohoo submitted form, and prevented default!')
  await win_open1();
});
```

Now you can see I added the call to the `win_open1()` function at the end. The next step is declaring that function to begin with `async`:

```js
async function win_open1() { ... }
```

So here is a fully updated script that opens windows, not sure if this was your goal but hopefully you can get some progress with it. It is important to organize and check for undefined variables before trying to access properties `.checked` and methods. You may not see the windows open on the SO code runner, but it does show one on [jsfiddle if you allow it](https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/aupcjnqw/6/). Edit: Updated the function to take a parameter of the `checkbox` since it was doing the same thing twice.

#### NOTE!! See updated version below this snippet!!

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('woohoo submitted form, and prevented default!')

  let cb_vb01 = document.getElementById('vb01');
  let cb_vb02 = document.getElementById('vb02');

  await win_open(cb_vb01);
  await win_open(cb_vb02);
});

async function win_open(cb) {
  let cb_vl = document.getElementById('vl');
  let cb_va = document.getElementById('va');
  let dok = '';
  
  // cb "vl" doesn't exist in OP code...
  if (cb_vl && cb_vl.checked == true) {
    dok = cb_vl.value;
  } else {
    dok = '';
  }

  if (cb && cb.checked == true) {
    let href = (cb_va) ? cb_va.value + cb.value + dok : cb.value + dok;
    console.log('cb href: ' + href);
    window.open(href, '_blank');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="va" id="va" type="hidden" value="https://example.com/index.php?op=gt&lang=pol&bdm="> Type: A: <input type="checkbox" id="vb01" name="vb" value="B&w=01ds&rid=B"> B: <input type="checkbox" id="vb02" name="vb" value="S&w=01ds&rid=S">
  <button type="submit">--- search ---</button>
</form>
```

## Edited Version!

Here is an updated version based on the full links that the OP had provided in the comments. I added some code comments to help. Remember there are plenty of ways to do this, so this is just one I came up with now. Check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/48tmg516/) of the updated code to see the popups, because they might not work on the SO code snippet.

```js
// get hidden field + text input elements
const va = document.getElementById('va');
const vc = document.getElementById('vc');
const vd = document.getElementById('vd');
const ve = document.getElementById('ve');
const vf = document.getElementById('vf');
const vg = document.getElementById('vg');
const vh = document.getElementById('vh');
const vi = document.getElementById('vi');
const vj = document.getElementById('vj');
const vk = document.getElementById('vk');

// get one last checkbox for "dok" var
const vl = document.getElementById('vl');

// get the form 
const form = document.getElementById('form');

// on the submit of form, prevent the actual submit to open popups
form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // returns a simple array with the link value of each popup
  let links = getAllHrefs();
  console.log(links);

  if (links.length <= 0) {
    console.log('No windows to open.')
    return false;
  }


  // NOTE: The client must allow pop-ups to open in their Browser Site Settings
  // This applies for Chrome/FF/Brave/etc.
  // They will not show on stackoverflow because:
  // The request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set
  // loop through array and open each popup, and wait 3 seconds.
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    // open window in new tab
    window.open(links[i], '_blank');
    // return promise to wait 3ms
    await new Promise(r => {
      setTimeout(r, 3000)
    })
  }
});

// creates an array of objects with props: 
// 1) name(input name) 2) val(input value)
function getFormDataToObj(selector) {
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  var eleArray = Array.prototype.map.call(ele, function(obj) {
    return {
      'name': obj.name,
      'val': obj.value
    };
  });
  return eleArray;
}

function getAllHrefs() {
  // get all "checked" checkboxes with cb-vb class 
  var cbArray = getFormDataToObj('.cb-vb:checked');
  if (cbArray.length <= 0) {
    console.log('At least one checkbox must be checked.')
    return false;
  }

  // get the "dok" variable, using ternary operator
  var dok = (vl.checked) ? vl.value : '';

  // setup query string for textbox, using String Literal
  var tb_vd = `&vd=${vd.value}`;
  var tb_vf = `&vf=${vf.value}`;
  var tb_vh = `&vh=${vh.value}`;
  var tb_vj = `&vj=${vj.value}`;

  // href link pattern per OP
  // va + vb01 + vc + vd + ve + vf + vg + vh + vi + vj + vk + dok
  var hrefs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cbArray.length; i++) {
    // setup the format for href, using a String Literal

    let href = `${va.value}${cbArray[i].val}${vc.value}${tb_vd}${ve.value}${tb_vf}${vg.value}${tb_vh}${vi.value}${tb_vj}${vk.value}${dok}`;
    hrefs.push(href);
  }

  // return array of links to open in popup
  return hrefs;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="va" id="va" type="hidden" value="https://example.com/index.php?op=gt&lang=pol&bdm=">
  <input name="vc" id="vc" type="hidden" value="&vc=vc_hidden_value">
  <input name="ve" id="ve" type="hidden" value="&ve=ve_hidden_value">
  <input name="vg" id="vg" type="hidden" value="&vg=vg_hidden_value">
  <input name="vi" id="vi" type="hidden" value="&vi=vi_hidden_value">
  <input name="vk" id="vk" type="hidden" value="&vk=vk_hidden_value">
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="vd">VD</label><input id="vd" name="vd" type="text" placeholder="VD" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb01">CB 01</label><input id="vb01" class="cb-vb vb-01" name="vb01" type="checkbox" value="&vb01=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb02">CB 02</label><input id="vb02" class="cb-vb vb-02" name="vb02" type="checkbox" value="&vb02=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb03">CB 03</label><input id="vb03" class="cb-vb vb-03" name="vb03" type="checkbox" value="&vb03=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb04">CB 04</label><input id="vb04" class="cb-vb vb-04" name="vb04" type="checkbox" value="&vb04=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb05">CB 05</label><input id="vb05" class="cb-vb vb-05" name="vb05" type="checkbox" value="&vb05=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb06">CB 06</label><input id="vb06" class="cb-vb vb-06" name="vb06" type="checkbox" value="&vb06=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb07">CB 07</label><input id="vb07" class="cb-vb vb-07" name="vb07" type="checkbox" value="&vb07=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb08">CB 08</label><input id="vb08" class="cb-vb vb-08" name="vb08" type="checkbox" value="&vb08=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb09">CB 09</label><input id="vb09" class="cb-vb vb-09" name="vb09" type="checkbox" value="&vb09=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb10">CB 10</label><input id="vb10" class="cb-vb vb-10" name="vb10" type="checkbox" value="&vb10=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb11">CB 11</label><input id="vb11" class="cb-vb vb-11" name="vb11" type="checkbox" value="&vb11=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb12">CB 12</label><input id="vb12" class="cb-vb vb-12" name="vb12" type="checkbox" value="&vb12=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb13">CB 13</label><input id="vb13" class="cb-vb vb-13" name="vb13" type="checkbox" value="&vb13=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb14">CB 14</label><input id="vb14" class="cb-vb vb-14" name="vb14" type="checkbox" value="&vb14=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb15">CB 15</label><input id="vb15" class="cb-vb vb-15" name="vb15" type="checkbox" value="&vb15=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb16">CB 16</label><input id="vb16" class="cb-vb vb-16" name="vb16" type="checkbox" value="&vb16=checked" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="vf">VF</label><input id="vf" name="vf" type="text" placeholder="VF" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb17">CB 17</label><input id="vb17" class="cb-vb vb-17" name="vb17" type="checkbox" value="&vb17=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb18">CB 18</label><input id="vb18" class="cb-vb vb-18" name="vb18" type="checkbox" value="&vb18=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb19">CB 19</label><input id="vb19" class="cb-vb vb-19" name="vb19" type="checkbox" value="&vb19=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb20">CB 20</label><input id="vb20" class="cb-vb vb-20" name="vb20" type="checkbox" value="&vb20=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb21">CB 21</label><input id="vb21" class="cb-vb vb-21" name="vb21" type="checkbox" value="&vb21=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb22">CB 22</label><input id="vb22" class="cb-vb vb-22" name="vb22" type="checkbox" value="&vb22=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb23">CB 23</label><input id="vb23" class="cb-vb vb-23" name="vb23" type="checkbox" value="&vb23=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb24">CB 24</label><input id="vb24" class="cb-vb vb-24" name="vb24" type="checkbox" value="&vb24=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb25">CB 25</label><input id="vb25" class="cb-vb vb-25" name="vb25" type="checkbox" value="&vb25=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb26">CB 26</label><input id="vb26" class="cb-vb vb-26" name="vb26" type="checkbox" value="&vb26=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb27">CB 27</label><input id="vb27" class="cb-vb vb-27" name="vb27" type="checkbox" value="&vb27=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb28">CB 28</label><input id="vb28" class="cb-vb vb-28" name="vb28" type="checkbox" value="&vb28=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb29">CB 29</label><input id="vb29" class="cb-vb vb-29" name="vb29" type="checkbox" value="&vb29=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb30">CB 30</label><input id="vb30" class="cb-vb vb-30" name="vb30" type="checkbox" value="&vb30=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb31">CB 31</label><input id="vb31" class="cb-vb vb-31" name="vb31" type="checkbox" value="&vb31=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb32">CB 32</label><input id="vb32" class="cb-vb vb-32" name="vb32" type="checkbox" value="&vb32=checked" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="vh">VH</label><input id="vh" name="vh" type="text" placeholder="VH" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb33">CB 33</label><input id="vb33" class="cb-vb vb-33" name="vb33" type="checkbox" value="&vb33=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb34">CB 34</label><input id="vb34" class="cb-vb vb-34" name="vb34" type="checkbox" value="&vb34=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb35">CB 35</label><input id="vb35" class="cb-vb vb-35" name="vb35" type="checkbox" value="&vb35=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb36">CB 36</label><input id="vb36" class="cb-vb vb-36" name="vb36" type="checkbox" value="&vb36=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb37">CB 37</label><input id="vb37" class="cb-vb vb-37" name="vb37" type="checkbox" value="&vb37=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb38">CB 38</label><input id="vb38" class="cb-vb vb-38" name="vb38" type="checkbox" value="&vb38=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb39">CB 39</label><input id="vb39" class="cb-vb vb-39" name="vb39" type="checkbox" value="&vb39=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb40">CB 40</label><input id="vb40" class="cb-vb vb-40" name="vb40" type="checkbox" value="&vb40=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb41">CB 41</label><input id="vb41" class="cb-vb vb-41" name="vb41" type="checkbox" value="&vb41=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb42">CB 42</label><input id="vb42" class="cb-vb vb-42" name="vb42" type="checkbox" value="&vb42=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb43">CB 43</label><input id="vb43" class="cb-vb vb-43" name="vb43" type="checkbox" value="&vb43=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb44">CB 44</label><input id="vb44" class="cb-vb vb-44" name="vb44" type="checkbox" value="&vb44=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb45">CB 45</label><input id="vb45" class="cb-vb vb-45" name="vb45" type="checkbox" value="&vb45=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb46">CB 46</label><input id="vb46" class="cb-vb vb-46" name="vb46" type="checkbox" value="&vb46=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb47">CB 47</label><input id="vb47" class="cb-vb vb-47" name="vb47" type="checkbox" value="&vb47=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb48">CB 48</label><input id="vb48" class="cb-vb vb-48" name="vb48" type="checkbox" value="&vb48=checked" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="vj">VJ</label><input id="vj" name="vj" type="text" placeholder="VJ" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb49">CB 49</label><input id="vb49" class="cb-vb vb-49" name="vb49" type="checkbox" value="&vb49=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb50">CB 50</label><input id="vb50" class="cb-vb vb-50" name="vb50" type="checkbox" value="&vb50=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb51">CB 51</label><input id="vb51" class="cb-vb vb-51" name="vb51" type="checkbox" value="&vb51=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb52">CB 52</label><input id="vb52" class="cb-vb vb-52" name="vb52" type="checkbox" value="&vb52=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb53">CB 53</label><input id="vb53" class="cb-vb vb-53" name="vb53" type="checkbox" value="&vb53=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb54">CB 54</label><input id="vb54" class="cb-vb vb-54" name="vb54" type="checkbox" value="&vb54=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb55">CB 55</label><input id="vb55" class="cb-vb vb-55" name="vb55" type="checkbox" value="&vb55=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb56">CB 56</label><input id="vb56" class="cb-vb vb-56" name="vb56" type="checkbox" value="&vb56=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb57">CB 57</label><input id="vb57" class="cb-vb vb-57" name="vb57" type="checkbox" value="&vb57=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb58">CB 58</label><input id="vb58" class="cb-vb vb-58" name="vb58" type="checkbox" value="&vb58=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb59">CB 59</label><input id="vb59" class="cb-vb vb-59" name="vb59" type="checkbox" value="&vb59=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb60">CB 60</label><input id="vb60" class="cb-vb vb-60" name="vb60" type="checkbox" value="&vb60=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb61">CB 61</label><input id="vb61" class="cb-vb vb-61" name="vb61" type="checkbox" value="&vb61=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb62">CB 62</label><input id="vb62" class="cb-vb vb-62" name="vb62" type="checkbox" value="&vb62=checked" /></td>
        <td><label for="vb63">CB 63</label><input id="vb63" class="cb-vb vb-63" name="vb63" type="checkbox" value="&vb63=checked" /></td>
        <td bgcolor="red"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="vl" class="cb-vl" name="vl" type="checkbox" value="&vl=checked" /> <label for="vl">VL</label></td>
        <td colspan="16"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I need to explain, My code is few times bigger, and I short it for showing here - but other parts are only multiple case. There is 63 checkboxes (from vb01-vb63), 4 text inputs (vd,vf, vh,vj), 6 hidden inputs with text (va,vc,ve,vg,vi,vk) and one other check value (vl). All of them make url addresses (va-vl). You can check for example 10 boxes (vbXX) and fill texts - and by submit you got 10 new pages open each with different address (each after 3 second of waiting).  - This form is for genealogist using databases.

Comment: more explanation: So address should be for each window va+vbxx+vc+...+vk+dok

Comment: Oh ok, interesting. Does my example answer, or are you looking for an update?  
And just wanted to clarify...    
if `vb01` is `checked` url is:  
`va + vb01 + vc + vd + ve + vf + vg + vh + vi + vj + vk + dok`
if `vb02` is `checked` url is:
`va + vb02 + vc + vd + ve + vf + vg + vh + vi + vj + vk + dok`  
if `vb03` `not checked`, do not open window?

Comment: yes, exactly, how this should work... (and `dok` is add when `vl` is `chcecked`) - (already exist). I just don't understand this part `if (cb && cb.....` but I will try to upgrade my code with you suggestion. `if vb03` `not checked`, do not open window and don't wait 3 sec.

Comment: Makes sense! There are tons of different ways to accomplish this. I can update my answer if I have time. So the `if (cb && cb.checked)` is what's called a [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation). I typically always check to make sure the element exists/not undefined first, and then check the `.checked` property. The `cb` in that instance is coming from the parameter of that function, which is the two checkboxes, `vb01` & `vb02`, using `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Take a look at the updated version if you still are looking into this. I put in some comments along the way, so hope you are able to get it figured out, but let me know.

Comment: No, sorry, it doesn't work. I might do some wrong - but I applied all your script - and after submitting I received address in THE SAME WINDOW like: mypage.com/index.php??va=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.coml%2Findex.php%3Fop%3Dgt%26lang%3Dpol%26bdm%3D&vb=B%26w ... and also vl doesn't work (not exist in this address, with or without checking the box). I did not change anything in your JS code. I check this in FF and Edge

Comment: maybe this is important - my server works with php 5.8

Comment: Well I should have added this. Most browsers block pop-ups either completely or after one pops-up. So for example, on this [jsfiddle using Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/48tmg516/), you have to allow pop-ups from that website in the browser site settings. It will show in the URL bar a red X that says it blocked the pop-ups if not. I see `vl` added after `vk` at very end. See `line: 65` The code says: Set `dok` if `vl.checked` then `dok = vl.value` else `dok = '' (empty string)`. Lastly, any version of `PHP` is fine, won't affect this. I tested Chrome, FF, & Brave too, all working.

Comment: still the same ... result is in the same window/tab  - as `_blank` would not exist. - tried on three browsers - two machines (popups totally enabled). Maybe something wrong is with `[i]` ?. ( `vl` works - my fault.)

Comment: Well that is just strange to me, I can only make it not work when the site settings are turned off. [I took a screen capture of it working on my machine, using Chrome latest version](https://www.treckstar.net/assets/images/2022-06-28-SO-two-window-open-one-function.webp). I added a link into the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/48tmg516/) as well. Is there any console errors on your end?

Comment: All I can think of at this point, is you don't want new tabs, you want actual whole windows to open? And if so, I don't think that is possible anymore with the way new browsers handle the `window.open()` function.. Firefox allows a `secondary window` to be opened, but that is the limited to 1 extra window. There are plenty of hacks out there if you want to try them, but if that is the case, [there isn't anything reliable, and generally should be avoided if at all possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#avoid_resorting_to_window.open).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245985/discussion-between-marcin-and-treckstar).